# Xamarin.Android Firebase auth crash

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-authentication

Im using Firebase authentication 42.1021.1 (latest stable).
In OnCreate method I have the following:

```
var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);
var authIntance = FirebaseAuth.GetInstance(firebaseApp);
```

But getting firebaseApp as null. After each clean re-build it works normally.

Note: I have the 'google-service.json' build action set as GoogleServicesJson.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem using this library. There is no solutions yet, you need to rebuild each time in order to make it works.

You can follow issue here :

https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/64
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56108

And a discussion on Xamarin Forum :
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/96263/default-firebaseapp-is-not-initialized-in-this-process

May be you can try with the new prerelease version of the package nugget "42.1024.0-beta1" or downgrade it while you are debugging.

Hope this will be fixed soon by Xamarin team !